# django admin login not redirecting

Tags: django, django-admin

I am able to browse django admin login page but upon keying in correct login details it will stay on the same login page with empty textboxes. It will show messages if login details are wrong though.
I have the following, what ways can I troubleshoot as the log doesn say anything significant.

What the ways to test login on the shell?

Use manage.py createsuperuser to create superuser as I missed the default one during running syncdb

Cleared cookies and retry still the same.

Correct SITE_ID in settings.py

```
settings.py
import logging 
import pwd
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
DEBUG_TOOLBAR = False
PROFILER_ON = False
INTERNAL_IPS = (
'127.0.0.1'
)

ADMINS = (
    ('Admin', 'test@domain.com'),
)

SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = False
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@domain'
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

EMAIL_HOST = 'test'

UPLOAD_ROOT = '/domain/uploads'

 PUBLIC_UPLOAD_ROOT = '/domain/htdocs/public_uploads'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'table_name',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
    # use this to create InnoDB tables
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=InnoDB',
        'charset': 'utf8',
    }
}
}

#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# Setup logging
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = (
  ('en-us', _('English(US)')),
)

SITE_ID = 1
SITE_NAME = 'my site'

USE_I18N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

PUBLIC_UPLOAD_URL = '/public_uploads/'

UPLOAD_URL = '/uploads/'


UPLOAD_IMAGES_DIR = 'images/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/djangomedia/'

SECRET_KEY = 'test'

#SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

#SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'domain'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)


LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/users/main/'
# The URL where requests are redirected for logout.
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
)

urls.py
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Show full `settings` please. Maybe you have some custom cookies or session setup there?

Comment: It was actually due to SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True in my settings.py, I had it accidentally defined in 2 places, one commented another one uncommented causing that to happen since the site is not running under https yet. It was silly mistake

Comment: Please close your question then

Comment: how should i close the question?

Comment: Write an answer (that it was due to... the best is something useful to other people with the same problem or who accidentally read it, e.g. specify whether `= True` is good or bad and why?) and *Accept* that answer next day. (You need not vote for it, but accept it.)

Comment: Check the SESSION_ENGINE variable. Try to set up the variable (using cookies only to test):

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"

If this fixes the problem then you probably have a problem with permissions.

Comment: Please post the answer to your problem as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

> It was actually due to SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True in my settings.py, I had it accidentally defined in 2 places, one commented another one uncommented causing that to happen since the site is not running under https yet. It was silly mistake – user1076881 Apr 5 at 7:27